# Apollo client setContext is not a function when running tests with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, apollo, apollo-client, babel-jest

I've been updating a frontend application developed using **React 16 (CRA 3 ejected)** to **React 17** in order to use MUI5 and other newest resources.

However, at some point (I don't know exactly when it started) my tests broke with the following message:

```
 TypeError: (0 , _context3.setContext) is not a function

      14 |   useEffect(() => {
      15 |     const initClient = async () => {
    > 16 |       const link = await (async () => setContext(() => ({
         |                                       ^
      17 |         headers: {
      18 |           'myHeaderInfoKey': myPublicHeader,
      19 |         },
```

This same test was working before other library updates. I haven't updated the Jest or apollo versions.

**The updates:**

- "@babel/core": "^7.17.9" from 7.7.4
- "react": "17.0.2" from 16.12.0
- "react-dom": "17.0.2" from 16.12.0
- "babel-loader": "^8.2.5" from 8.0.6
- "babel-loader": "8.0.6" from 7.4.0

**The additions**

- "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0"
- "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^7.12.13",
- "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^7.12.13",
- "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
- "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",

**Kept:**

- "jest": "24.9.0",
- "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
- "@apollo/client": "^3.1.2",

The jest.config.json is like this:

```
{
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "!src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "setupFiles": [
    "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
  ],
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
  "testMatch": [
    "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  ],
  "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
    "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
  ],
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "web.js",
    "js",
    "web.ts",
    "ts",
    "web.tsx",
    "tsx",
    "json",
    "web.jsx",
    "jsx",
    "node"
  ],
  "watchPlugins": [
    "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
    "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
  ]
}
```

**Edit**
Here is the test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { ApolloLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { SchemaLink } from '@apollo/client/link/schema';
import useApiClient from './useApiClient';

const triggerConnection = ({ apiUrl= '', xApiHeaderPublic = '', sleepTime = 0 }) => {
  const { client } = useApiClient({ apiUrl, xApiHeaderPublic, sleepTime });
  return { client };
};

test('Connects to a url', async () => {
  const wrapper = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;
  const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => triggerConnection({
    apiUrl: '',
    xApiHeaderPublic: '',
    sleepTime: 0,
  }), { wrapper });
  await act(async () => {
    await waitForNextUpdate();
  });
  expect(result.current.client).toBeTruthy();
  expect(result.current.client.link).toBeTruthy();
  expect(result.current.client.link instanceof ApolloLink).toBeTruthy();
  expect(result.current.client.link instanceof SchemaLink).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Here is the **useApiClient**:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';

const useApiClient= (
  {
    apiUrl,
    xApiHeaderPublic,
    sleepTime,
  } = { apiUrl: '', sleepTime: null },
) => {
  const [client, setClient] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initClient = async () => {
      const link = await (async () => setContext(() => ({
        headers: {
          'myHeaderInfoKey': myPublicHeader,
        },
        uri: apiUrl,
      })).concat(new HttpLink()))();

      setClient(
        new ApolloClient({
          cache: new InMemoryCache(),
          link,
        }),
      );
    };

    initClient();
  }, [apiUrl, xApiHeaderPublic, sleepTime]);

  return { client };
};

export default useApiClient;
```

Can anyone give me a tip about how to handle it?

Comment: The error message you are getting here suggests that you are mocking Apollo without providing a mock for `setContext` specifically.

Comment: Could you share your test file code please?

Comment: Hey @Marcus, just added.

Comment: Are you mocking apollo client anywhere? Are you perhaps using a `__mocks__` folder?

Comment: Hey Marcus, sorry for my late reply. Actually, I've already resolved that by removing the ^ from the `"babel-loader": "8.2.5",` dependency and cleaning up the environment cache, node_modules, yarn.lock...

I needed to be rushed with this, so I didn't go deep and also didn't retry using the ^ to make sure that it was something related to incompatibility.

Comment: No problem, glad you were able to sort it out.